# Write PendingIntent to parcelable

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I need to save PendingIntents if my app finishes. For some reason I don't have reference to wrapped intent neither to other arguments of PendingIntent creation process. Just a reference to PendingIntent. So my first idea was to write PendingIntent to JSON-string and save it as String. But GSON-library gives me back StackOverflow error (seems like I can't transform PendingIntent to JSON). Now my idea is to save PendingIntent within Parcel to sdcard. However creating PendingIntent from Parcel returns null (as well as Intent).

```
Intent intent = new Intent("TEST_ACTION");
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeParcelable(intent, 0);
intent = parcel.readParcelable(null);
Log.d("DBG", (intent == null) + "");
```

Output is `true`

Comment: "I need to save PendingIntents if my app finishes" -- that is not really possible AFAIK. "For some reason I don't have reference to wrapped intent neither to other arguments of PendingIntent creation process" -- I believe strongly that you are going to have to fix that. "Now my idea is to save PendingIntent within Parcel to sdcard" -- a `Parcel` is not designed to be written to disk.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Client-code sends me just a reference to PendingIntent, I think it would be a bad architect solution to ask for all parameteres and create PendingIntent on my side. However it's my fault, I thought Parcelable could be used for object-persistence as well as serializable.

Comment: But is there a way to persist Intent?

Comment: "I think it would be a bad architect solution to ask for all parameteres and create PendingIntent on my side" -- that is fine, but then you cannot "save PendingIntents if my app finishes". "But is there a way to persist Intent?" -- an `Intent` can be converted to a string via `toUri()` and converted back from a string into an `Intent` via `getString()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html